# Is it ok to ask questions solely for validating a result?

Tags: discussion

If I have solved a problem to 99% certanity, and just want to make sure it's right, is it ok to post it on MSE?

Very drooling example:

"Can someone please verify that $1+1=2$ ?"

Or is the proper way to ask the question and then use Q&A style to answer it myself?

Comment: If you already know the answer, on this site you should avoid posting just to answer yourself. Posts of that form are better on a personal blog. Instead, if there is a specific part of your argument you are unsure about, write a question to emphasize that.  If there is no particular thing you want to ask about, the question may not be a good fit for this site. Questions that just ask "is this correct" are hard to answer if the answer is "yes".

Comment: From the hypothetical $1+1=2$ example it is not clear to me what this type question would really look like. Anyway, if you look in past discussions in the tags ([meta-tag:solution-verification]) and ([meta-tag:self-answer])  on meta, some of them might be related to what you want to ask

Comment: A statement, whether you are 99% certain or not, does not amount to a Question.  Being in a fog about something is unlikely to produce a good post.  If you can figure out a specific point that you are having difficulty with, it might be the basis of a good Question.